# Kivy [widget] has no attribute [child_widget]

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I am attempting to use the [remove_widget](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.remove_widget) function to make my button disappear after it has been clicked. According to the [documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets) I believe this is the correct way to accomplish this. However when I attempt to remove the button I get a crash. Not sure if this has to do with reference types to the widget or something else.

Here is my main.kv

```
<MainPanel>:
orientation: 'vertical'
spacing: 1

AppActionBar:
    size_hint: (1., 0.1)

ScrollView:
    id: scrollview_main
    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: False if root.fullscreen else (content.height > root.height - dp(16))
    AnchorLayout:
        id: anchorlayout_main
        size_hint_y: None
        height: root.height if root.fullscreen else max(root.height, content.height)
        GridLayout:
            id: content
            cols: 1
            spacing: '8dp'
            padding: '8dp'
            size_hint: (1, 1) if root.fullscreen else (.8, None)
            height: self.height if root.fullscreen else self.minimum_height
            Button:
                id: button_open_process
                size_hint_y: None
                text: 'Open New Process'
                height: '48dp'
                width: '120dp'
                on_release:
                    root.open_process()
                    root.remove_widget(root.button_attach_process) <-- offending line
                    #root.remove_widget(root.button_open_process)
            Button:
                id: button_attach_process
                size_hint_y: None
                text: 'Attach to Currently Running Process'
                height: '48dp'
                width: '120dp'
                on_release: root.attach_process()
```

And the error I get when clicking the button with id `button_open_process`

```
AttributeError: 'MainPanel' object has no attribute 'button_attach_process'
```

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little awkward to be managing dynamic widgets in kv, but in any case the problem is that setting an id doesn't set an attribute of the root widget - that's why it doesn't exist. You can instead do `root.remove_widget(button_attach_process)` directly, or `root.remove_widget(root.ids.button_attach_process)` which would also work in a python file.